How to implement input validation loop for integer conversion in Python?
I'm working on a Python exercise to convert numbers using bin(), oct(), and hex().
I want to implement input validation to ensure the user enters a valid integer.
Current code:
pythonCopynum = int(input('Inform a number to convert: '))

This code breaks with a ValueError if the input is not a valid integer.
I'd like to implement a loop that continues to prompt the user until a valid integer is entered, without throwing an exception.
Desired behavior:
Prompt user for input
If input is not a valid integer, display an error message and prompt again
Repeat until a valid integer is entered
How can I modify my code to achieve this input validation loop?
Additional info:

Using Python 3.
Prefer a solution that doesn't rely on external libraries

Any suggestions on implementing this efficiently would be appreciated.

Well, you can either (1) check the value before hand by using isdigit or similar, or (2) put it in a try/except block to catch any errors.  I prefer the first option, but many argue for the second.

Thanks, guys! It can be acutally made in a very simple way with "if" and "while" using the .isnumeric option.
Still, I'll make sure to study both for future uses, since I've just begun studying programming in general and I've been putting myself through some harder challenges.

There are 3 ways I can think of it:
First Approach - Using try catch:
loop until you won't get ValueError
def get_valid_integer():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input('Inform a number to convert: ')
            num = int(user_input)
            return num
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

# Call the Function
num = get_valid_integer()

Second Approach - Using .isdigit()
Get it as string and check if its a digit using .isdigit()
def is_valid_integer(s):
    return s.lstrip('-').isdigit()

def get_valid_integer():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Inform a number to convert: ')
        if is_valid_integer(user_input):
            return int(user_input)
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

# Use the function
num = get_valid_integer()

Third Approach- Hooking the keyboard.
Assuming you are using windows for example- you can use Win32API.
Hook every key on your keyboard and drop it if it's not a number. But this solution is over engineering for your need.
